# Why is the convention to send (contact) form data to server?

Tags: javascript, html

If I do all validations client-side and just want the submitted form's data sent to an email (no need to store it on server), why do all contact form solutions seem to include the server in the process?

Comment: Because the client can interfere with the client-side validation. ***Never*** trust anything that has been sent to the client. You *must* revalidate on the server.

Comment: Because the "client" is simply the client, and it can only send data to the server. Can't send e-mails, can't access other websites content, etc... It's like a box whose only connection is to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `client-side` JavaScript can't send emails..

In any case, most people don't store the data on the server, they just use it to do the validation (which is important, as javascript can be disabled!)

Comment: JavaScript **can** be used to send emails, but *browsers* can’t.

Comment: @David If JavaScript is running from a browser, surely that means that it can't?

Comment: Yea, just wanted you to clearify that :] JavaScript *as a language* does not have that limitation, especially now when nodeJS has gained popularity.

Answer (score 2):

Because *you* are sending the email, not the user, so the data used to construct the email has to be sent to your server for you to put it in the email. The data doesn't need to be stored though.

Websites do not have the ability to instruct the user's email software (assuming the user *has* email software) to send emails on their behalf.